# ReadThreadProfilingData () - Cannot get HPC values

Tags: performancecounter

I have an issue with ReadThreadProfilingData(). What I want to do, is to count the number of instructions get executed by the current thread (only
the instructions executed in user-mode). I can't use directly RDPMC as I'm in user-mode. Windows provides HPC API which is exactly what I need. Here's my code:

```
PERFORMANCE_DATA pd;        
HANDLE           hdl, thd_hdl;

ZeroMemory(&pd, sizeof(PERFORMANCE_DATA) );

pd.Size            = sizeof(PERFORMANCE_DATA);
pd.Version         = PERFORMANCE_DATA_VERSION;
pd.HwCountersCount = 1;

thd_hdl = GetCurrentThread();
thd_hdl = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, GetCurrentThreadId() );

EnableThreadProfiling(thd_hdl, 0, (DWORD64)0x02, &hdl);
// this returns ERROR_SUCCESS

for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++ );     // do something
printf("Number of HPC returned: %d\n", pd.HwCountersCount );
ReadThreadProfilingData(hdl,READ_THREAD_PROFILING_FLAG_HARDWARE_COUNTERS, &pd);
// this also returns ERROR_SUCCESS

DisableThreadProfiling(hdl);

printf("Number of HPC returned: %d\n", pd.HwCountersCount );
```

In the above code, I'm reading performance counter #1 (instructions retired).

Although all functions are return ERROR_SUCCESS, pd.HwCountersCount is 0 which means that ReadThreadProfilingData() doesn't really read anything.

What I'm doing wrong? Is there any alternative way to count the number of
instructions get executed by current thread?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and think it may be necessary to call the KeSetHardwareCounterConfiguration(...) function to configure the hardware counters before the thread profiling is enabled:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd796399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The help page for KeSetHardwareCounterConfiguration is:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

However, I get hundreds of compiler errors when I include both "Windows.h" and "ntddk.h". If you cannot find "ntddk.h" on your system, then you need to install the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

Comment: The KeSetHardwareCounterConfiguration can only be called from within a driver. I suppose that's how Agner Fog's implementation works: http://www.agner.org/optimize/testp.zip

Answer (score 0):

To profile hardware performance counters, you need a driver to configure the counters. The performance counters are configured globally for the system, so every thread has access to the same hardware counter data. The counters must be configured before you enable profiling. For information on configuring hardware performance counters, see the KeSetHardwareCounterConfiguration function in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

OR try using the Intel PMU